# How to cancel subscription of EventBus events sent by itself?

Tags: android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

I've got 2 running classes registered for **EventBus** events - instance **A** and instance **B**. Both of them have implemented `onEvent(SampleEvent event)` method for receiving `EventBus.post(new SampleEvent(int foo, String bar));` from a place **C**. So far so good.

But there is a time when I need to post `SampleEvent` **from B to A**. Is it possible to tell **B** that it shouldn't process `SampleEvent` sent by itself, or I need to do workaround like setting a flag in `SampleEvent`?

Comment: Why are you not using a separate event when sending an event from B to A?

Comment: @PeterP This is also a way. The thing is that it would be totally same event with the same variables, only different name. If my idea isn't possible to acomplish, I would go exactly this way. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to extend SampleEvent for exmaple SampleEventToA than you check within B by using reflection:

```
if  (! event instanceof SampleEventA){
    //do things here
}
```

Found this issue on otto EventBus: Derived events from super event will also call the subscriber of the super event. This would be a possible OO solution!

https://github.com/square/otto/issues/83

Comment: Thanks, good idea that I haven't think of. However not exactly the answer I was looking for.